# How is possible to have variable with the same name but different type in c?

Tags: c, variables, types

Having this header and .c files:

*foo.h*

```
extern void * Foo;
struct Foo { unsigned val; };
```

*foo.c*

```
int main(){
    void * Foo;
}
```

It compiles correctly, but there are 2 variables with 2 different types (`void*`, `struct {...}`) but with the same name.

How's that possible?

How does the compiler know which is which?

Comment: `struct Foo { unsigned val; };` declares a type `struct Foo`, not a variable.

Comment: so if I do not use the `struct Foo` before variable named `Foo`, compiler will always presume to mean `void*` becuase it is `extern`? what if I made `extern struct Foo` ?

Comment: There are two different variables in your code, but both have the same type. `extern void* Foo;` declares a global variable named `Foo`, which is declared but never defined (so if you ever tried to use it, you get a linker error), and `void * Foo;` inside `main` defines a local variable that's unrelated to the global variable.

Comment: If you have `struct Foo { /*whatever;*/ };` the identifier `Foo` by itself does not "exist" in C. You need `typedef struct Foo { /*whatever;*/ } Foo;` to create the identifier in global namespace. In the first case, the identifier `Foo` exists in the struct namespace: `struct Foo`

Comment: The variable `Foo` defined in `main` and the variable `Foo` declared in `foo.h` refer to different entities. Also, the `struct Foo` is irrelevant to the other `Foo`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct Foo` is a type you created, `Foo` is not a declared variable, it's part of the type name.

A variabe of type `struct Foo` with the name `Foo` would be declared as follows:

```
struct Foo  Foo;
^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^
   ||        |
  type      name
```

Only then would there be two variables with the same name:

```
struct Foo { unsigned val; }; //new type

extern void* Foo; // variable named Foo of type void*
struct Foo Foo;   // variable named Foo of type struct Foo
```

This code would produce the expected error:

> *`error: conflicting types for ‘Foo’`*